# JSON data not returned from controller to view?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I tried to send my data from controller to view using JSON. In one funtion, it was working fine, but in another it is not working. When I debug I found data is passed from controller, but not get returned in view.

Here is my code

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult LoadEmployee(string E_Id)
        {
           var _Employee= ApplicationManager.GetEmployee(E_Id);
            if (_Employee != null)
            {
                ViewBag.EmployeeName = _Employee.User != null ? _Employee.User.LoginName : string.Empty;
                ViewBag.Department = _Employee.Department != null ? _Employee.Department : string.Empty;
                ViewBag.JobTitle = _Employee.JobTitle != null ? _Employee.JobTitle : string.Empty;
                ViewBag.RegNo = ReportManager.GetEmployee(E_Id);
                ViewBag.employeeName = ReportManager.GetEmployeeFullName(E_Id);
            }
            var data1 = ViewBag;
            return Json(data1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

In View:

```
function Select() {
        var t = $('#tblEmployee').DataTable();
        var rowData = t.rows('.row_selected').data();
        var E_Id = rowData["0"].EmployeeId;

        var EmployeeDetailsIdUrl = '@Url.Action("LoadEmployee")';
             $.ajax({  
                type: "GET",  
                url: EmployeeDetailsIdUrl,  
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
                data: { "E_Id": E_Id },  
                datatype: "json",  
                 success: function (data1) {  
                     $('#modal-info').modal('hide');
                     $('#txtEmployeeId').val(E_Id);
                     $('#txtEmployeeName').val(data1.EmployeeName);
                     $('#txtRegNo').val(data1.RegNo);
                     $('#txtJobTitle').val(data1.JobTitle);
                     $('#txtDepartment').val(data1.Department);

                  },  
                error: function () {  
                    alert("Dynamic content load failed.");  
                }  
            });  
          }
```

FYR, I added my data1 format, due to company rules, I hided few data's.

[image]

How to send my data from controller to view? Data1 is in dynamic view, when debug, I found it. Kindly help.

Comment: did u get any error ? 
did u console the data1 and find ur expected data ?
and what is `txtEmployeeId` is it input id or html tag id?

Comment: no,I am not getting any error. And my expected data sent from controller( in dynamic view), but not received in view. `var E_Id = rowData["0"].EmployeeId;` My employee Id is the one that selected from pop up modal sent to controller, using this Id , I retrieve all the other data under data1 and tried to display it in my textboxes. `txtEmployeeId` and all other id's start with 'txt', is my text boxes ids..

Comment: @NijinKoderi I am sending my data from viewbag to variable data1.. This data1 is returned to view. I tried to send my viewbag directly too, still not able to get in view.

Comment: if your data1 has value then problem might be how you are setting ur data
can u plz provide ur data1 value and ur view code

Comment: @sayalok Kindly take a  look on my question again, I attached image of how data1 format..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I tried various ways, this one fixed my problem and its working for me:

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult LoadEmployeeDetails(string E_Id)
        {

             var _Employee= ApplicationManager.GetEmployee(E_Id);
            var data1= new
            {
                 EmployeeName = _PREmployeeSalary.User != null ? _PREmployeeSalary.User.LoginName : string.Empty,
                Department = _PREmployeeSalary.Department != null ? _PREmployeeSalary.Department : string.Empty,
                JobTitle = _PREmployeeSalary.JobTitle != null ? _PREmployeeSalary.JobTitle : string.Empty,
                RegNo = DailyLeaveReportManager.GetEmployee(E_Id),
                employeeName = DailyLeaveReportManager.GetEmployeeFullName(E_Id)
            };
             return Json(data1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You receive your whole response object in the success method, so I think you should have

```
success: function (response) {  
                 $('#modal-info').modal('hide');
                 $('#txtEmployeeId').val(E_Id);
                 $('#txtEmployeeName').val(response.data1.EmployeeName);
                 $('#txtRegNo').val(response.data1.RegNo);
                 $('#txtJobTitle').val(response.data1.JobTitle);
                 $('#txtDepartment').val(response.data1.Department);
```

You could try inspecting what you actually receive in the UI with F12 in the browser.